# SFML font loading from memory doesn't function correctly when using a vector + emplace_back() to add an object with font member variable in C++ SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using the SFML library and programming in C++.
I made a `TextButton` class for buttons who have various member variables, some being sf::Text, sf::Font.
I create a vector named `buttons` to store all `TextButton` objects in one place. When I need to draw them, I loop through said vector and use `TextButton::draw()`.
For each button I load the font from memory using an array that contains the binary data of the font.

When I am using `vector.emplace_back()` to create the `TextButton` objects directly in the vector and then draw the text of the button, I get a segmentation fault. But when I first create the `TextButton` objects separately and then use `vector.push_back()` to add them to the vector, code works fine and no segmentation fault occurs.
Also, when I add only one button to the `buttons` vector using `vector.emplace_back()`, also no segmentation fault occurs (it occurs only when I use emplace_back() and atleast 2 buttons in the vector).

`TextButton` class:

```
class TextButton {
    public:
    using Action = void(*)();

    private:
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Vector2f size;
    Action action;
    
    sf::RectangleShape shape;
    sf::Text text;
    sf::Font font;

    public:
    TextButton(const sf::Vector2f& position, const sf::Vector2f& size, const sf::Color& color,
               const unsigned char* binaryFont, const unsigned int binaryFontSizeInBytes,
               const int characterSize, const sf::Color& textColor, const std::string& label, Action action);

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) const;

    bool is_clicked(const sf::Vector2f& mousePosition) const;

    void on_click() const;
};

TextButton::TextButton(const sf::Vector2f& position, const sf::Vector2f& size, const sf::Color& color,
                       const unsigned char* binaryFont, const unsigned int binaryFontSizeInBytes,
                       const int characterSize, const sf::Color& textColor, const std::string& label, Action action) 
: position(position), size(size), action(action) {
    shape.setSize(size);
    shape.setPosition(position);
    shape.setFillColor(color);

    font.loadFromMemory(binaryFont, binaryFontSizeInBytes);
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setString(label);
    text.setCharacterSize(characterSize);
    text.setFillColor(textColor);

    sf::FloatRect textBounds = text.getLocalBounds();

    text.setOrigin(textBounds.left + textBounds.width/2.f, textBounds.top + textBounds.height/2.f);
    text.setPosition(position.x + shape.getSize().x/2.f, position.y + shape.getSize().y/2.f);
}

void TextButton::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) const {
    window.draw(shape);
    window.draw(text);
}

bool TextButton::is_clicked(const sf::Vector2f& mousePosition) const {
    return position.x <= mousePosition.x && mousePosition.x <= position.x + size.x &&
           position.y <= mousePosition.y && mousePosition.y <= position.y + size.y;
}

void TextButton::on_click() const { action(); }
```

Code in which I create and draw the buttons (with some irrelevant code stripped)
(Note: I have created the RenderWindow as `window`):

```
std::vector<TextButton> buttons;

    //case when I use emplace_back() and get a segmentation fault:
    buttons.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f(200.f, 200.f), sf::Vector2f(300.f, 80.f), sf::Color::Green, low_bit_pixel_ttf, low_bit_pixel_ttf_len, 30, sf::Color::Black, "button 1", []{ std::cout << "first button pressed\n"; });
    buttons.emplace_back(sf::Vector2f(500.f, 350.f), sf::Vector2f(200.f, 60.f), sf::Color::Red, low_bit_pixel_ttf, low_bit_pixel_ttf_len, 30, sf::Color::White, "button 2", []{ std::cout << "second button pressed\n"; });

    //case when I use push_back() and everything works fine:
    //TextButton button1(sf::Vector2f(200.f, 200.f), sf::Vector2f(300.f, 80.f), sf::Color::Green, low_bit_pixel_ttf, low_bit_pixel_ttf_len, 30, sf::Color::Black, "button 1", []{ std::cout << "first button pressed\n"; });
    //TextButton button2(sf::Vector2f(500.f, 350.f), sf::Vector2f(200.f, 60.f), sf::Color::Red, low_bit_pixel_ttf, low_bit_pixel_ttf_len, 30, sf::Color::White, "button 2", []{ std::cout << "second button pressed\n"; });

    //buttons.push_back(button1);
    //buttons.push_back(button2);
    
    while(window.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) { window.close(); return false; }
            if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Left) {
                sf::Vector2f mousePosition = sf::Vector2f(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window));
                for(auto& button : buttons) {
                    if(button.is_clicked(mousePosition)) {
                        button.on_click();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        for(auto& button : buttons) {
            button.draw(window);
        }

        window.display();
    }
```

I think it has something to do with the font variable being destroyed or the binary data not being accessible when using `emplace_back()`, because the segmentation fault appears here in `window.draw(text)`:

```
void TextButton::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window) const {
    window.draw(shape);
    window.draw(text);
}
```

But I can't pinpoint why. I would say it is because `emplace_back()` does something differently that make the binary data or the `font` variable inaccessible, *but then how do you explain that when I emplace_back only one button, no segmentation fault occurs?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text.setFont(font);` stores the address of `font` inside `text`.

When you add elements to the vector and you exceed its `capacity`, `std::vector` will allocate new memory and copy everything to the new location, including the `text` and `font` members. However, your `text` is still referring to the **old address** of `font`, not the new address.

Since this behavior is dependent on the implementation of `std::vector` there are really only two general solutions:

1. make the copy constructor of `TextButton` update the `font` pointer of your `text` member, or
2. Use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<TextButton>>`. In this case resizing the vector will copy the pointers, but the objects will remain fixed in place.